# Translate regex substitution from RegEXR to work in bash script

Tags: regex, bash, global, osx-mavericks, multiline

I am trying to create a regex substitution command in bash script, but after playing with single quotes, double quotes and escape characters, I am pulling my hair out. I use RegEXR to compose patterns and came up with following:

**I search for:**

```
/\.icon-(.*) {\n\t/gm
```

**and want to replace it with:**

```
if(strpos(\$embedicons,'$1') !== false) { \$svgicons .= <<<'EOD'\n\.$1 {
```

**This replaces this:**

```
.icon-basket-14-icon {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,blahblah');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**with this:**

```
if(strpos($embedicons,'basket-14-icon') !== false) { $svgicons .= <<<'EOD'
.basket-14-icon {background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,blahblah');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

However, I am pretty unsuccessful in making it happen within a bash script. I am not sure it is relevant, but I am on OSX Mavericks and use Terminal app. While the patterns in RegExr make sense to me, once I start escaping it, I completely lose track of what is going on.

1. How to make sure the regex is global and multiline?
2. Is it better to use some other option than builtin regex?
3. Is there a resource online that teaches (bash) regex to complete noobs?
4. Is there a group pattern that matches everything (including whitespace and
   newlines) until a given chain of characters like an asterisk (*) ?

Obviously I am not looking for a handout, as this problem haunts me regularly... I would love to learn regex and solve my problems by learning and I studied some examples online, but they seem far too advanced. Maybe there is an online generator like RegExr that translates into bash compatible and PHP compatible versions of regex patterns?

---

**UPDATE/SOLUTION:**

The following seems to work for me in OSX Mavericks terminal:

```
sed "s|\.icon-\(.*\) {|if(strpos(\$embedicons,'\1') !== false) { \$svgicons \.= <<<'EOD' \.\1 {|g"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `sed` for this kind of replacement, this line will do what you want:

```
sed "s/^.icon-\(.*\) {$/if(strpos(\$embedicons,'\1') !== false) { \$svgicons .= <<<'EOD'\n.\1 {/"g input_file.txt
```

input_file.txt:

```
.icon-basket-14-icon {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,blahblah');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Output:

```
if(strpos($embedicons,'basket-14-icon') !== false) { $svgicons .= <<<'EOD'
.basket-14-icon {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,blahblah');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

With the `-r` (extended regex) flag set, you only need to escape literal braces and the variable dollar signs in your example.

With regards to your questions:

- the `g` flag for `sed` makes it global. What exactly do you mean by "multiline"? Outputting newlines is easy using \n, matching across lines is a bit more complex as `sed` operates line by line. A common technique is to replace all newlines in the file/data with a placeholder, perform the regex/substitution with the placeholder in mind, then replace the placeholder with newlines again.
- `sed` is probably your best bet for regex-type stuff. You can find documentation online, this is fairly comprehensive: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

For the last part, using `(.*)` will capture everything, then you just have to handle the newlines and make sure you escape your terminating string properly.

testfile:

```
testing data with space -
and newlines /'\ *** ends
there
```

Command (`tr` is swapping newlines for tildes and back again):

```
tr '\n' '~' < testfile | sed -r 's/(.*)\*\*\*.*/\1/g' | tr '~' '\n'
```

Output:

```
testing data with space -
and newlines /'\
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, for your reply. I am trying to test it straight away. It seems my version of sed (on OSX Mavericks) doesn't like the -r option. When removed, see complains: sed: 1: "s/^.icon-(.*) \{$/if(st ...": RE error: invalid repetition count(s)

I will play with it a bit and try to make it work. Thanks so much for your long reply and all the hints. Every bit of knowledge is a milestone for me.

Comment: You can remove the -r flag, then you would have to escape syntactical braces and parentheses. I cannot test right now but will edit.Will be back later on if you cannot get it working!

Comment: So, with your help, I managed to get somewhere. I am not sure how amateurish that looks like, but this works for me right now: 

`sed "s|\.icon-\(.*\) {|if(strpos(\$embedicons,'\1') !== false) { \$svgicons \.= <<<'EOD' \.\1 {|g"`

I had to replace the \ in sed with | otherwise the picket fence made my brain go numb. I gave up on replacing the newlines. I now understand tr takes strings of the same length and I am afraid tilde (~) can show up in the code somewhere one day and mess it all up. It would be great if I could replace newlines with a long string and then back after sed is done.

Comment: You can use sed again in place of tr, just a longer command and probably more expensive: `sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/PLACEHOLDERSTRING/g'` to remove newlines, `sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/PLACEHOLDERSTRING/\n/g'` to replace them.